# I cannot delete a view

Tags: views

I installed the module "himuesgallery" in a Drupal 7 site, and created two image galleries. To display them on one page, I created a view. When I try to remove the view, the system is showing me the message: "The view has been deleted." It seems to be ok, but it isn't. The view is still there and can't be deleted.

I also flushed the cache, but nothing changed. DO you have any idea?

Answer (score 3):

It happened to me also.

After hours of trying, I removed the records in the database:

1. VIEWS_VIEW > remove the view (remember the 'vid' value of the view)
2. VIEWS_DISPLAY > remove all the displays with that vid